# Trying to use VB.NET to get a list of Discord Channels

Tags: .net, vb.net, discord.net

Trying to get a list of Text Channels for a Discord Category.

I have the following code and it brings in a SocketChannel object that lists all the channels as an indexed string inside the DiscordChannelList but I can't figure out how to loop through that channel list. I'm sure I have to some how cast it to another type but since the Channels isn't a property available to a SocketChannel I'm not sure how to do it.  Sorry, I'm just a hobby programmer when it comes to this type stuff so any guidance would be appreciated.

```
        Dim DiscordChannelList as SocketChannel
        Dim CategoryId As ULong = 999999999999999999
        DiscordChannelList = _client.GetChannel(CategoryId)
```

Comment: It is usually useful to supply more context around your question and anuy preceeding code some someone can get more of an idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Cast it to a `SocketCategoryChannel`

Comment: Thank you so much. That got me what I needed